# Request to retrieve sum(total) based on user country

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, orders and clients.

> they are linked to eachother with a foreign key 'client' in orders table to 'id' primary key in clients table.

They are setup as follows:
Clients

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.clients
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('clients_id_seq'::regclass),
    locationstreet text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    locationcity text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    locationcountry text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    joinedin timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT clients_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Orders

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.orders
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass),
    client integer NOT NULL,
    total real NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,

    CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_client_fkey FOREIGN KEY (client)
        REFERENCES public.clients (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT orders_couponused_fkey FOREIGN KEY (couponused)
        REFERENCES public.coupons (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
)
```

Basically the output i want looks something like this:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Country       | Total |
+---------------+-------+
| United states | 150   |
+---------------+-------+
| Morocco       | 3300  |
+---------------+-------+
| Sweden        | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
```

basically i want to see a list of distinct countries, and next to it the sum(total) of all orders made by users that live in that country using client.locationcoutry

Please help me if you have any ideas

Comment: Join the tables, then aggregate. Where exactly is the problem? Your data model would be better with a separate country table by the way. As is, you can easily have typos (Marocco, Maroco, ...) and thus get undesired results.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ill look into that, but for now the all data is being submitted through a website which only lets users select valid country names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation using a `Sum()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT clients.locationcountry AS country,
    SUM(orders.total) as total
FROM clients
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders 
        ON clients.id = orders.client
GROUP BY country;
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ensures that if a `client` record doesn't have even a single `order` record, it will still show up in the output (total for that record would be 0 unless other clients that have orders are also located in the same country).